# How to use xdebug with routing?

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, content-management-system, xdebug

I am using xdebug for my PHP scripting. For now, this is working quiet good.

What doesn't work, is using a breakpoint for AJAX calls, which have a specific route. For example, within my symfony application, I defined the following route:
Point `/relationlist/fetchJsonList` to function `/extensions/vendor/cnd/relationlist/Extension.php::fetchContentElementArray()`

The breakpoints within this method never breaks. I have tried to

1. append the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug`
2. use the Chrome xdebug *extension*

My PHP xdebug module settings:
https://jsbin.com/tebofifete

**Further info:**
I am trying to debug an extension, where I use the following to declare my route.

```
$this->app->get("/relationlist/finditems/{contenttype}/{field}/{search}", array($this, 'findItems'));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is xdebug working on that port normally? I'm not sure what IDE you're using, but in PHPStorm you choose "break on first line" in the run menu, which should work as long as you set the port right in the settings and are listening for connections.

Comment: show your routing and the controller action

Comment: @mickadoo: "Break on first line" is working. I am using Sublime with martomo/SublimeTextXdebug.

Comment: @PatrikKarisch: I updated my post with more info